# Github pulling, without using a github account?

Tags: github, ssh

I have a small embedded linux system image which I deploy for users. It has a Python project on it that checks github using `git ls-remote --heads` for changes and does a `git pull` to pull the latest version.

There is no need for writing anything to the repository, it's actually better if that's not possible, since these systems are outside of my control. Because of that I also don't like to put my own Github credentials on it.

Is it possible to use Github in this sort of semi-public manner?
If so, what would be a good minimalistic (i'm guessing SSH) setup?

(by the way, this used to work, but recently stopped working, I've not figured out why yet. I have never before set up any key's or whatever, so i'm guessing this should be possible..)

Answer (score 0):

You can just clone the repo:

```
git clone git://github.com/SomeUser/SomeRepo.git
```

The local repo will be "read-only" in the sense that you won't be able to push your changes back to the remote repo. You will still able to modify files and commit changes locally.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use HTTPS (https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/)
2. Configure git as follows to suppress the self-signed cert warning: `git config --global http.sslVerify false`